# Discontinuity of Dirichlet function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Define $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}, \\
0, & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}$$Then $f$ has a discontinuity of the second kind at every point $x$, since neither $f(x+)$ nor $f(x-)$ exists.

**Proof:** We'll consider only for $f(x+)$.

*Case 1*. If $x_0\in \mathbb{Q}$ then we can take $t_n=x_0+\frac{1}{n}$ at that $t_n\to x_0,t_n>x_0$ and $t_n\in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence $f(t_n)=1\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Also we can take $t_n=x_0+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ at that $t_n\to x_0,t_n>x_0$ and $t_n\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $f(t_n)=0\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

*Case 2.* For $x_0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ we apply a similar argument.

We can take $t_n=x_0+\dfrac{1}{n}$ and in this case $f(t_n)\to 0$. Taking $t_n\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_0<t_n<x_0+\dfrac{1}{n}$ we get $f(t_n)\to 1.$

Hence $f(x_0+)$ does not exists at any point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Also $f(x_0-)$ does not exists at any point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$.

Hence Dirichlet function has discontinuity of the second kind at every point of $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Is my proof true?

Comment: If you know that $q + \frac{\sqrt{2}} n$ is irrational for every rational number $q$ and integer $n$, then yes, your proof is OK for $f(x_0 +)$. You need to clarify why it's also good for $f(x_0-)$

Comment: @5xum, yes i know this. It's easy to prove. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP was told that the proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is correct.

To summarize, the key point is to "construct", or show the existence of, if one wishes, two decreasing or increasing convergent sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that
they both converge to the same given point,
but $(f(x_n))$ and $(f(y_n))$ have different limits.

You implicitly use the following two facts in your proof:

- (1) the sum of a rational and an irrational is irrational;
- (2) the set of rational numbers is dense in the real line.

You may also use the fact that [the set of irrational numbers is dense in the real line](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1121166) together with (2) to give a proof.