# Proof there is an irrational number $r$ in every intervall $a < r < b$

Tags: real-analysis

> Proof that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an irrational number $r$ so that
>   $a < r < b$. Basically, proof, that between any two irrationals, there is another irrational r.

I'm sure there are already many ways out there how to do it, however I have troubles proving it in the following way:

(1) For every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a bijective function between $[0,1]$ and $[x,y]$ (already proven)

(2) $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \in ]0,1[$

(3) Now  when mapping $[0,1]$ onto $[x,y]$ $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ will also be mapped into the new intervall, therefore there has to be an irrational number in $[x,y]$

Now the problem I see is, that for example $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ could be mapped onto a rational number and therefore I'd have to proof, that there is a different irrational in $[x,y]$. It'd be nice if you could help me complete the proof.

Comment: do you have a description of the bijective function? or would like to only use the existencE?

Comment: @clark only use the existence

Comment: your proof does not mention $a$ and $b$ at all

Comment: What do you mean when you say you need to prove that there is a different irrational in [x,y]? Doesn't every non-empty open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ have an irrational?

Comment: @JMoravitz It's not about the result it is about the way

Comment: @RajivKaipa Well that is bascially what has to be proven, or rather, that between any to irrationals that is another irraitonal

Comment: If the statement that has to be proved is irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then the link provided by JMoravitz should answer that part right? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935808/proof-that-the-set-of-irrational-numbers-is-dense-in-reals) should answer that as well. Another way you could prove it is by stating that fact that group with elements of the form $n - m\xi$ where $\xi$ is irrational and $n$ and $m$ are integers is an additive group which is not not cyclic, which implies that it is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

If there are only rational numbers in $[x, y]$, then $[x, y]$ is countable and is in bijection with $[0, 1]$ which is uncountable, which is impossible.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to continue your proof, then define $m = \frac{a + b}{2}$, $n = \frac{(a + b)\sqrt{2}}{2}$. You can show that $a < m < n < b$. Then either:

1. $m$ is irrational, and you're done.
2. $m$ is rational, then $n = \sqrt{2}m$ is the product of a rational and an irrational, and so is irrational, and you're done.

Comment: why should n be less than b? If a=2, b=3, then n=3.53... Unfortunately your arguments does not work

Comment: You're right, I think my brain was off.