# Dense and nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ be a non-empty subset of $X$. Then one can conclude that if $X\setminus A$ is nowhere dense in $X$, $A$ is dense in $X$,

Is the above statement true in general? I know if $A$ is open then the result is true, but I am not sure otherwise.

Comment: In case it could be of use, I gave (for metric spaces) some equivalences of "has empty interior", and also of "is nowhere dense", in my answer to [Is saying a set is nowhere dense the same as saying a set has no interior?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886341/is-saying-a-set-is-nowhere-dense-the-same-as-saying-a-set-has-no-interior/1886404#1886404).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not true in general.

Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$. Clearly $A = \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is also [known to be dense as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935808/proof-that-the-set-of-irrational-numbers-is-dense-in-reals).

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

No, as others pointed out already. Sets can be dense and co-dense, like the rationals and the irrationals in the real numbers.

But $A$ is nowhere dense iff $X\setminus \overline{A}$ is dense. So something close to it is true.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is dense $\Rightarrow A^-=X\Rightarrow A^e=\emptyset \Rightarrow A^{c\circ}=\emptyset$. $A^{c\circ}=\emptyset$ does not always imply $A^{c-\circ}=\emptyset$, since $A^c\subseteq A^{c-}$.